# Set mod_expires in past date

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i use .htaccesss to control my expire content

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 24 hour"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "now"
</IfModule>
```

The thing that annoys me is my index.html page, i want to have expire date in past so all changes i made on file to be updated on user browser as well.

`ExpiresByType text/html "now"` is not working i want something like: `ExpiresByType text/html "past"`

Any ideea how i can do this?

Comment: Use instead `modified plus <x> days/hours/minutes`

Comment: @hjpotter92 what modified do? thanks

Comment: Read about the _Interval Syntax_ on this page: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_expires